# Xcode 4.5 project warning - "Upgrade Compiler configuration to LLVM"

Tags: ios, xcode4.2, xcode4.5, compiler-warnings, llvm-gcc

I moved a project originally coded in XCode 4.2 to XCode 4.5 and now I am getting the following warning when i build -

> The compiler configuration is set to 'com.apple.compilers.llvmgcc42'. This will upgrade to 'Apple LLVM compiler 4.1', which is recommended setting for iOS targets'

I am unable to understand what versions of compilers are being referred. I searched for compiler version, but I am still confused between the terms "Apple LLVM" and "LLVM GCC". Pls help.

Comment: Don't worry about LLVM GCC, It will not exist starting in the version of Xcode that comes after 4.6 (4.7 or 5.0)

Comment: I still want some clarity about the terms. A summary on the difference between these compilers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following are steps to overcome this warning

1. Just Click on Project Target.
2. Build Settings > Build Options.
3. GCC_VERSION: < Select "Default compiler (Apple LLVM compiler 4.1)" or preferred one >
4. Clean and build your app

**EDIT**

For your doubt about difference , I would like you to take a look at the following links.

1. [Link 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4589335/llvm-vs-gcc-for-ios-development)
2. [Link 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020349/difference-between-llvm-gcc-4-2-and-apple-llvm-compiler-3-1)
3. [Link 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3739783/iphone-gcc-llvm-gcc-or-llvm)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I knew about the changes in build settings. I just want to know why I'm getting this warning. Whats the difference b/w Apple llvm and llvm gcc. And if there is other jargon I should know about.