# File size limit for read()?

Tags: python, macos, python-2.7, file, python-3.x

I'm running into a problem while trying to load large files using Python 3.5. Using `read()` with no arguments sometimes gave an `OSError: Invalid argument`. I then tried reading only part of the file and it seemed to work fine. I've determined that it starts to fail somewhere around `2.2GB`, below is the example code:

```
>>> sys.version
'3.5.1 (v3.5.1:37a07cee5969, Dec  5 2015, 21:12:44) \n[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5666) (dot 3)]'
>>> x = open('/Users/username/Desktop/large.txt', 'r').read()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
>>> x = open('/Users/username/Desktop/large.txt', 'r').read(int(2.1*10**9))
>>> x = open('/Users/username/Desktop/large.txt', 'r').read(int(2.2*10**9))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

I also noticed that this does not happen in Python 2.7. Here is the same code run in Python 2.7:

```
>>> sys.version
'2.7.10 (default, Aug 22 2015, 20:33:39) \n[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.1)]'
>>> x = open('/Users/username/Desktop/large.txt', 'r').read(int(2.1*10**9))
>>> x = open('/Users/username/Desktop/large.txt', 'r').read(int(2.2*10**9))
>>> x = open('/Users/username/Desktop/large.txt', 'r').read()
>>>
```

I am using OS X El Capitan 10.11.1.

Is this a bug or should use another method for reading the files?

Comment: I guess the file loading capacity is mainly dependent on How much free memory your device is having, at that point of time.

Comment: I thought that might be a problem but: A) I have 16GB and only 8 are used right now. B) it works fine if i switch to python2.7

Comment: From what is shown in the first snippet of output, it looks like the `>>> x = open('/Users/username/Desktop/large.txt', 'r').read(int(2.1*10**9))` worked since no `OSError` was raised when it was executed. The varying results may also be due to the fact that two different compilers were used to build the Python interpreter. See [_Difference between LLVM, GCC 4.2 and Apple LLVM compiler 3.1_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12020349/difference-between-llvm-gcc-4-2-and-apple-llvm-compiler-3-1).

Comment: Yes, 2.1*10**9 works. I tried several values but noticed that it starts to fail somewhere in between 2.1 and 2.2.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you have bumped into a bug.

*Good news* is that someone else has also found it and already created an issue for it in the Python bug tracker, see: [Issue24658 - `open().write()` fails on 2 GB+ data (OS X)](https://bugs.python.org/issue24658). This, seems, is platform depended (OS-X only) and is reproducible when using `read` and/or `write`. Apparently an issue exists with the way `fread.c` is implemented in the libc implementation for OS-X see [here](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3413139?start=0&tstart=0).

*Bad News* is that *it is still open* (and, currently, inactive) so, you'll have to wait until it is resolved. Either way, you can still take a look at the discussion there if you're interested for the specifics.

---

As a solution, I'm pretty sure you can side-step the issue until it is fixed by reading in chunks and chaining the chunks during processing. Do the same when writing. Unfortunate but, it might do the trick.

Comment: the bug report even mentions a stack overflow post! what would python do without SO ?

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre probably be a lot more buggy :-)